# How to handle day of week adjustment

Tags: date, datetime, excel-formula, leap-year, alteryx

I am trying to resolve an issue involving comparing Year Over Year data results by day, and cant seem to quite figure it out.

I want to be able to accurately compare Year Over Year results by a specific day - Historically we have been calculating this as [Years Back] * 364  to obtain the number of days between the two dates, but as the yearly difference becomes greater than  7 it becomes incorrectly calculated.

I attached a picture here showing the anomaly where there is not a constant difference YoY and between two dates. 2015 is not a leap year.

Labor Day vs Memorial Day - YoY:
[image]

What is the best way to calculate any given dates past equivalent date? If I have two calendar tables, what do I match on? (I can get any of the following fields to match  Date, Day of Week Number, Day of Month November, Week Number of Month, Week number of Calendar Year etc.)
For example, need to input the date, and have an output of past year equivalent
Like So:

```
Given Date | Past Year equivalent
20190902   | 20180903
20190902   | 20170904   
20190902   | 20160905   
20190902   | 20150907   
20190902   | 20140901
```

Comment: Please correct me, but are you looking for a formula that essentially says 'find the closest date to a year back that has the same day of the week'?

Comment: @healey No I am looking for the specific equivalent date for all years back. Its tricky to describe this... We want to be able to compare year over year results for that day of the year, the third friday of this month should be equivalent to the third friday of the month last year. Another scenario which more accurately depicts the issue is memorial day. Memorial day is the last monday of May, falls on different dates every year, and can be in the 5th or 6th week of the month.

Comment: It looks like the `WEEKDAY` formula will be your friend. Check out [this article](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/522868-how-to-calculate-the-third-friday-of-a-month.html) about calculating the nth day of a month. Let me know if you need help to generalise the formula.